# Webmin and Email Server

Tags: email, webmin

I'm new to using **Webmin** as a server on my **Ubuntu Server OS**.

Here's the thing. I bought a **domain** from my ISP and I'm using **Webmin** to connect my Webmin server to the domain and that part is done and now I'm stuck at configuring my Email server. Well actually not stuck. I'm not really sure what to use as my Email server whether it's Postfix or Sendmail. I just want to have my own @myaddress.com from the domain that I bought.

Help me on what email server to use and it's basic configuration file! Thank You. Any help is much appreciated!